# Python read multiple excel file error

Tags: python, excel

I have 2 Excel files and I need to load this data into a database use python. but only can load 1 file. The other file will cause an error to display. If I put a file in folder, it will run well.

I use xlrd read excel file.

I import xlrd as ExcelRead .

**2 file name in folder**

CN SU HC Report(FW15).xls

CN WX HC Report(FW16).xls

**Code..**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":  
# Import HC data to database
    result=[]
    findfiles(r'D:\Tableau_Report\HR','CN * HC*.xls')
    for filename in result:
        print filename
        readHC(filename)
```

**Reslut：**

> "C:\Python27\python.exe" -u "D:\Tableau_Report\HC.py" 
>       CN SU HC Report(FW15).xls

```
('Suzhou', '38766', 'AN, 'Male', '2006-07-11', '2006-07-11', 'Employee', '38889', Coronado', 'Indirect', 'SUCH-N', 'Asia Engineering ', 'Drive Operations', '14034', 'Sr Engineer') 

CN WX HC Report(FW16).xls

open D:\Tableau_Report\HR\CN WX HC Report(FW16).xls error, error is __import__() argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str
```

**readHC function**

```
   def readHC(file_name):
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join('D:\Tableau_Report\HR',file_name)):      
            try:  
                xls = ExcelRead.open_workbook(os.path.join('D:\Tableau_Report\HR',file_name))  
                sheet = xls.sheet_by_index(0)  
            except Exception, e:  
                print "open %s error, error is %s" %(os.path.join('D:\Tableau_Report\HR',file_name), e)  
                return
        else:
            print "open %s error, file not exist!" %(os.path.join('D:\Tableau_Report\HR',file_name))
            return  
    ......
    ......
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Remove the try/except so you get a full traceback to indicate where the error is occuring.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tableau_Report\HC1.py", line 304, in <module>
    readHC(files)  
  File "D:\Tableau_Report\HC1.py", line 103, in readHC
    xls = ExcelRead.open_workbook(os.path.join('D:\Tableau_Report\HR',file_name))  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 425, in open_workbook
    from . import book
TypeError: __import__() argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str